# R script error : attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r

I am trying to code the Gravitational Search Algorithm in R language to tune Xgboost, but I am facing an error: `Error in xgb_model$set_params(as.list(particle_positions[i, ])) :  attempt to apply non-function`
The error appears when I try to evaluate the initial position:

```
# Evaluate the initial particle positions
for (i in 1:n_particles) {

  xgb_model$set_params(as.list(particle_positions[i, ]))
  resampling <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats = 5, verboseIter = FALSE)
  model_fit <- train(
    x = as.matrix(train[, -15]), y = train[, 15],
    method = "xgbTree", trControl = resampling,
    metric = "Accuracy", tuneLength = 0,
    maximize = TRUE
  )
  best_positions[i, ] <- particle_positions[i, ]
  best_values[i] <- model_fit$results[1, "Accuracy"]
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick, you are totally rigth, but after some investigation, it seems that my version of xgboost does not use `xgboost$set_params` it was on xgboost 0.6.1